# jQuery MMenu anyway to run up to browser size?

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I have an existing menu which should be shown if the screen sizes is more than 768px wide.
If the resolution is lower than 768px i would like to replace my menu with **[MMenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/)**.
Is there a way to run the mmenu script if the resolution is lower than 768px?

The Problem is that [mmenu](/questions/tagged/mmenu) takes  out of his place on put it under . This is the reason why it breaks my page design.

If you run this <kbd>[mmenu demo](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/demo/advanced.html?v=20140514)</kbd> and look at the source code you will see that the `<nav>` element is under `<div class="content">`. If you check it by using Firebug you will see that it is under `<body>` and that breaks the Design if it is more that 768px.

Comment: I understood the follwing. If window size is less than 768px the menu should be hidden (like in the demo before the click on the icon). If the resolution is > 768px (so already with 770px) the menu should be always visible (in the demo after the click on the icon). Is this correct?
Is this [question similar to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494530/)?

Comment: Oh yes thats the same question :) I will give a try.. Thanks

Comment: Ok I have tested with some Codes but it seems that I have to clone the complete Menu to be able to show it. `$("#menu").clone().attr('id', 'menu-original' ).addClass("hidden-xs").insertBefore("#menu");
$("#menu").mmenu();`